# Boost Graph Library - Graph with exactly N Edges/Vertex

Tags: c++, vector, boost, boost-graph

I am using the BGL adjacency list to portray a very regular graph, where I know exactly, that each vertex will have N edges.

This is my graph definition:

```
typedef boost::vecS OutEdgeList;
typedef boost::vecS VertexList;
typedef boost::no_property GraphProperties;
typedef boost::vecS EdgeList;

// Graph definition
typedef boost::adjacency_list<
            OutEdgeList,
            VertexList,
            boost::undirectedS,
            VertexProperties,
            EdgeProperties,
            GraphProperties,
            EdgeList
            > Graph;
Graph g;
```

I use a vector/vecS to store the connections and I suppose by naively calling `boost::add_edge` the list will get resized in need vector-like by something like twice its last size.

The graph uses a lot of RAM(~12GiB) and I don't want the vector when lets say N=9 to reserve for 16 connections.

Is there a memory efficient way to pre-initialize the adjacency list container like

```
for(auto edgesOfVert:edgesOfVerts)
    edgesOfVert.reserve(N);
```

or another way to make use of the regularity of the graph to save memory?

Thank you for any advice!

EDITED: As a possible solution I found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43851630/how-to-get-the-outedgelist-inside-a-bgl-graph/43855664#43855664) but I agree with sehe and consider reserving the right amount of edged inelegant, because it tries to force a use on a data structure not made for the particular task I need it for

Comment: I found at least a way to adjust the size of the edge list with `g.m_edges.reserve(N*num_verts);` I am reading further the BGL docs. Is there a way to iterate over the OutEdgeList to do the same for the 'inner' adjacency list  of the graph?

Comment: IMHO loading an entire graph of such size into memory is unlikely to be the way to go.  Simply visiting each edge would take too long.  I recommend thinking about your problem and finding a way to organize the data on disk in such a way you need only load the parts that you actually need when you need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real solution here would be not to use `boost::adjacency_list`. Instead, adapt your own data structures to model the Graph concept you need.

For example, there's the `grid_graph<>` model in the Boost Graph Library which (if I remember correctly) uses no storage for the vertices at all, and indeed knows exactly how many edges are going to exist between all nodes ahead of time.

You can still use all the graph algorithms that apply to the graph concepts modeled (`grid_graph<>` models `Incidence Graph`, `Adjacency Graph`, `Vertex List Graph`, `Edge List Graph`, `Bidirectional Graph`, `Adjacency Matrix`).

Also consider making the graph memory mapped so you do not have to "load it" fully, or even have to be able to fit it in RAM at any given time (beware of access times though, it will all depend on the access patterns and how you layout the data).

Comment: Implementing my own data structure is now about to be debated. And I am already playing with grid_graph but I want to compare all possibilities to one another :)  Memory mapping the graph would be like Serialize them to hard disk?

Comment: "like" but without the serializing step. Look at Boost Interprocess e.g. I have many answers around using it. Basically, it means working with self-contained data in such a way that it doesn't matter where the data is in memory (which means it can be paged in on demand).